# Xamarin Dynamically Added Buttons Not Being Displayed

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been writing an android app that generates a dynamic view when it has received data from a server.

I found then when trying to create the view when inside a different thread, the buttons aren't displayed, but the Linear Layouts are displayed.

For example, the following doesn't work...

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Task thread = new Task(() =>
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                ShowDynamicLayout();
            });
        });
        thread.Start();
        return;
    }
```

But this does...

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        ShowDynamicLayout();
        return;
    }
```

ShowDynamicView:

```
    private void ShowDynamicLayout()
    {
        var scrollView = new ScrollView(this)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent)
        };

        var mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this)
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
            LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent)

        };

        scrollView.AddView(mainLayout);

        for (int n = 1; n < 10; n++)
        {
            var dv = new DynamicView(this, n)
            {
                LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 100)
            };
            mainLayout.AddView(dv);
        }

        SetContentView(scrollView);
    }
```

DynamicView:

```
public class DynamicView : LinearLayout
{
    private List<LinearLayout> layouts;

    public DynamicView(Context context, int count) :
        base(context)
    {
        this.Initialize(count);
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        foreach (var l in this.layouts)
        {
            l.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w / this.layouts.Count, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        }
    }

    private void Initialize(int count)
    {
        this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        this.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 125, 0));
        layouts = new List<LinearLayout>();
        for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
        {
            var layout = new LinearLayout(this.Context)
            {
                Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                LayoutParameters =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.Width / count, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
            };

            layouts.Add(layout);

            var button = new Button(this.Context)
            {
                Text = "New button"
            };
            button.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(125, 0, 0));
            layout.AddView(button);

            this.AddView(layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Unthreaded:
http://www.crashm.co.uk/Working.PNG

Threaded:
http://www.crashm.co.uk/NotWorking.PNG

Comment: you are trying to do UI updates on a background thread - use RunOnUIThread

Comment: I am, and if you read the example you'll see that i'm already using RunOnUIThead

Comment: sorry, I completely missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found then when trying to create the view when inside a different thread, the buttons aren't displayed, but the Linear Layouts are displayed.

I don't know the deep root reason, but it seems when your codes are executed by the android system without thread. Android rerender your view.(you can see it when setting breaking point on `OnDraw` and check breaking times difference of threaded and not threaded).

Anyway, the problem lies in following line:

`LayoutParameters =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.Width / count, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)`.

inside Initialize function, because it is called in `OnCreate`, so at that time `this.Width` is always 0, because this view hasn't been measured. Thus your won't get expected view.

**Solution:**

You should separate your Initialization and render logic and call the render logic in `OnDraw` like this:

```
public class DynamicView : LinearLayout
{
    private List<LinearLayout> layouts;
    int count;
    public DynamicView(Context context, int count) :
        base(context)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        this.Initialize(count);

            foreach (var l in this.layouts)
            {
                l.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w / this.layouts.Count, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            }
    }


    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        //call the render logic in OnDraw
        FillView();
    }

    private void Initialize(int count)
    {
        //initialize logic
        this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        this.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 125, 0));
        layouts = new List<LinearLayout>();
    }

    //render logic
    private void FillView()
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
        {
            var layout = new LinearLayout(this.Context)
            {
                Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                Background = new ColorDrawable(new Color(0, 10, 0)),
                LayoutParameters =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.Width / count, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
            };

            layouts.Add(layout);

            var button = new Button(this.Context)
            {
                Text = "New button"
            };
            button.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(125, 0, 0));
            layout.AddView(button);

            this.AddView(layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: For anyone who uses this code in the future, you need to put a first time check around the FillView call, otherwise it will just keep creating new objects and will crash when it reaches the android object limit.